# nested for loop with type 'lxml.etree.ElementDepthFirstIterator' python3.4

Tags: for-loop, python-3.4

I am using python 3.4, trying to find the similar subtree in an xml file.

this is my code:

```
def find_unique_sub_tree(oneFile, resultPath, list_ignored_att):
      root = find_root(oneFile)
      idNodes = root.iter('xmlID')
      for n1 in idNodes: 
          id1 = n1.attrib['idName']
          for n2 in idNodes:
              id2 = n2.attrib['idName']
              do something
```

The problem with the nested for loop is that it takes only the first item from the outer loop and when finish from the inner loop it never goes back to take the second item from the outer loop. I understand the problem but could not solve it.
I tried these solutions:

```
idNodes = root.iter('xmlID')
idNodes2 = root.iter('xmlID')
for n1 in idNodes: 
      id1 = n1.attrib['idName']
      for n2 in idNodes2:
```

also I tried:

```
root = find_root(oneFile)
root2 = find_root(oneFile)
idNodes = root.iter('xmlID')
idNodes2 = root.iter('xmlID')
for n1 in idNodes: 
      id1 = n1.attrib['idName']
      for n2 in idNodes2:
```

these did not solve the problem.

and finally, I tried a deep copy but it give error:

```
root = find_root(oneFile)
idNodes = root.iter('xmlID')
idNodes2 = copy.deepcopy(idNodes)
for n1 in idNodes: 
      id1 = n1.attrib['idName']
      for n2 in idNodes2:
```

So I tried this:

```
idNodes = list(root.iter('xmlID'))
idNodes2 = copy.deepcopy(idNodes)
for n1 in idNodes: 
   id1 = n1.attrib['idName']
   for n2 in idNodes2:
```

It removes the error but did not solve the problem

Can anyone help with this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but you may be better off making a list of all child nodes and use a different function to compare each element in the list using whatever criteria is desired:

```
node_list = list()
for n1 in idNodes:
    node_list.append(n1.attrib['idName'])
x = 1
for idName in node_list:
    for idName2 in node_list[x:]
        result = compare_nodes(idName, idName2)
        x += 1
```